# How to get "smooth scrolling" system-wide?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, gtk

I found an amazing extension for Google Chrome called SmoothScroll. It makes scrolling webpages extraordinarily visually appealing, just like in opera.

I was wondering if I could find something like this for Ubuntu that can be applied system wide so that I can experience this on any scrollbar I use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it's a bit old, i found out that gnome 3.4 supports smooth scroll

> You will also see improvements to the building blocks that our applications have been made with. This includes smooth scrolling, refreshed user interface components, a much refined visual theme and application menus.

[library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.4/](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.4/)

Does anybody knows how to enable it?

Comment: While this isn't the absolute answer, at least it shows that it is available.

Comment: It will be enabled for all applications that use GTK3.4+. That includes Nautilus, gedit, and maybe others, on 12.04+

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does have a smooth scroll option too.

But as far as I know this is implemented in those applications (and AFAIK only for the browser window, not for other widgets?), not in standard Gtk widgets (or Xorg, or whatever), so no system-wide setting exists (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

No system-wide setting as applications need to handle **XInput 2.1 events** themselves or use a toolkit that does it automatically.

**Gnome/GTK3** applications handle smooth or pixel-perfect scrolling by default.

**Firefox** requires setting an environment variable `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2` (`echo 'export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1' >> ~/.xsessionrc`).

**Chromium** introduced it recently in version 54 and you will need to install it from an a source that is more up-to-date than Ubuntu's repositories.

**KDE/QT** apps apparently have support though I haven't tried.

**Electron**-based apps (such as Atom) don't have any support for XInput 2.1 events yet.

Comment: Wow this is an old question, I haven't been using Ubuntu since 2013. Also note however that MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 only works in Firefox when you have e10s enabled. This can be checked in about:support under Multiprocess Windows. Some extensions may not officially support e10s so you either have to disable the extension or set "browser.tabs.remote.force-enable" to true under about:config (however this isn't recommended).